# I get 'reference to MultivaluedHashMap is ambiguous' when try to run Java project after compiling with Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-8

Affected line are:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = new MultivaluedHashMap<>(uriInfo.getQueryParameters(false));
```

getQueryPararameters is the interface method:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> getQueryParameters(boolean var1);
```

Error:

> Error:(61, 49) java: reference to MultivaluedHashMap is ambiguous
>     both constructor MultivaluedHashMap(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) in javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap and constructor MultivaluedHashMap(java.util.Map) in javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap match

Comment: How is your urlInfo declared?

Comment: @Context UriInfo uriInfo

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml?

Comment: I have plenty of them, it will be to confusing to post them here, I can just add, that I've different versions of Jax-RS API

Comment: I'm suspecting that's the problem. The code looks right to me - a MultivaluedMap<String, String> is a Map<String, List<String>> so it should not match the constructor taking a Map, as that one would expect a Map<? extends String, ? extends String>. The error message is printing without generic types though, perhaps you have a jax-rs jar without generics in your dependencies...

Comment: After trying this myself (resolution works fine without amiguity in my test), I think @PerHuss is right - check your effective dependencies to see if you've got some ancient (pre-generics) version of the class in your classpath.

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and share the results...

Comment: Interestingly, there are *two* errors, one saying that the constructor was ambiguous because two constructors are applicable and the other saying that the constructor taking a `Map` is not applicable. But it can be compiled under Java 7 as well as under recent Java 9 previews (b66 and newer). I’d call this a compiler bug (a quick test with Eclipse revealed no problems) that will eventually get fixed. Until then, just use `new MultivaluedHashMap<String,String>(uriInfo.getQueryParameters(false))`.